# Extending c-mode, based on Java, how to tweak annotations?

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting

I'm working on modifying Haxe mode for Emacs. It is based on c-mode, Java language.

After this mode was created, the language introduced new construct, it is similar in style to Java annotations, except for one thing:

```
@:macro public function foo() { ... }
```

is an annotation too. I.e. the part "@:macro" is an annotation, but c-mode treats the annotation as if it had to be "@" symbol followed by letters (once it sees ":", it thinks it's the end of the annotation).

What is the rule it is using for parsing annotations and how would I modify it?

Below is something that I've tried to do, but it neither works, nor am I sure it's the right way to do it.

```
(defadvice c-forward-annotation
  (around haxe-forward-annotation ())
  "Overrides `c-forward-annotation' to be able to use @:\w+ syntax as well
as the Java original syntax."
  (message "c-forward-annotation overloaded")
  (and (looking-at "@")
       (progn (forward-char) t)
       (if (looking-at ":")
           (progn
             (forward-char)
             (c-forward-type))
         (c-forward-type))
       (progn (c-forward-syntactic-ws) t)
       (if (looking-at "(")
           (c-go-list-forward)
         t)))
```

The function seems to actually do the job properly, what doesn't work later is the `c-beginning-of-statement-1` - but it's too complex to find out what is actually happening...

One more thing I've tried:

```
(c-lang-defconst c-symbol-start
  haxe (concat "[" c-alpha "_@]:?"))
```

but didn't help either. Even some more info: if I <kbd>C-c C-s</kbd> on the line containing `@:macro` I get `cpp-macro` syntax, which is so ironically close, but not what I need.

More info: by overriding `c-beginning-of-macro` I could make it believe it is not a `cpp-macro`, however it is still not recognized as annotation. I've also overridden the place in `c-forward-decl-or-cast-1` where it had a hardcoded regexp for testing for Java-style identifiers... still no go :(

Also changed in the `(c-lang-defconst c-basic-matchers-after ...)` to the below, but still no go...

```
,@(when (c-major-mode-is 'java-mode)
    `((eval . (list "\\<\\(@:?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\)\\>" 1 c-annotation-face))))
```

Comment: Check out the definition of c-forward-label in cc-engine.el.

Answer (score 1):

I think I finally found it!

```
(c-lang-defconst c-cpp-matchers
  haxe (append
        (c-lang-const c-cpp-matchers c)
        '(("\\<\\([A-Z][A-Za-z0-9_]*\\)\\>" 1 font-lock-type-face))
        '(("\\<\\(@:?[A-Za-z]+\\)\\>" 1 c-annotation-face))))
```

I had to add the last matcher regexp to make it recognize the colon inside metadata. I'm still not sure about other changes that I've made and how important any of them was in respect to this final change that did it, but certainly this was an important one.